# Ways to work around DirectQuery in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, directquery

I'm working on a DirectQuery dataset in Power BI and I notice that Transform data/Query editor is disabled for DirectQuery mode, usually it'd return a message something like:

`This step results in a query that is not supported in DirectQuery mode.` when I tried to create a measure/new column/transform data.

What is the best way to modify data/create measures/columns when dealing with DirectQuery data?

Comment: That is how directquery is designed to work for...you will not be able to transform data/query editor operations when using direct query mode.

Comment: Hi @balaji you're right, but I found out if you create your modelling functions as new tables, then seems like you can transform data and visualise it as per normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectQuery comes with limitations as to what kinds of modeling and transformations you can do because the computations happen on the data source side.

Please refer to the documentation:

- [Use DirectQuery in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-use-directquery)
- [About using DirectQuery in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-about)

---

Given the inherent limitations, some things can be worked around but others just aren't feasible. Without specifics, I can't tell which is the case for your situation.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the documents, it is real time data stored in SQL database that requires DirectQuery. And I found that most Power Query or Power Editor functions are not supported in this case. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Not in general because any transformations have to be translated into SQL. If Power Query can't do that translation, then it can't be used in DirectQuery.